# pd.read_sql, how to convert data types?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am running a sql query from my python code and attempting to create a dataframe from it.  When I execute the code, pandas produces the following error message:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '*my connection info*' : expecting string or bytes object
```

The relevant code is:

```
import cx_Oracle
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd

dsn_tns = cx.makedsn('x.x.x.x', 'y',
                     service_name='xxx')
conn = cx.connect(user='x', password='y', dsn=dsn_tns)

sql_query1 = conn.cursor()

sql_query1.execute("""select * from *table_name* partition(p20210712) t""")

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query1,conn)
```

I was thinking to convert all values in query result to strings with df.astype(str) function, but I cannot find the proper way to accomplish this within the pd.read_sql statement.  Would data type conversion correct this issue?

Comment: `df = pd.read_sql("""select * from *table_name* partition(p20210712) t""", conn)` - the first argument to read_sql is the SQL string to execute; not a cursor.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thanks, yeah I tried that as well, but when I have it constructed in that manner the query does not complete.  When I have it as shown above, it completes fine.    it gives me message like 'attribute 'client_identifier' of 'cx_Oracle.Connection' objects is not readable' when I run it in debug.

Comment: "it completes fine." - well, you wouldn't be here asking if it does.

Comment: I meant the query part of the code, the issue is when I try to convert the query results to a dataframe